# Label is not printing any value in ASP.NET using VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Need your expertise on the issue.

**Background:** I have a label control in the presentation layer which is purely used for status display. Status could be Update Fail Pass/Delete/Duplicate record etc. that is  happening through GridView (refer Code 1).

The status in this label is shown using code behind procedure (refer Code 2)

**Issue:** The procedure is not displaying anything when called from `UpdateTableRecordInDatabase(...)` but it works when I hit the button (created test button to evaluate whether is there any issue in the code). I did the debug and the values are being passed successfully without any issues.

[image: On Click of Test Button]

**Code 1**

```
        <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" visible="false"></asp:Label>

        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="TablesUpdatePanel" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:GridView ID="ListOfTables" runat="server" AllowPaging="True"
                 AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                 DataKeyNames="PK_RestaurantTableID" 
                 DataSourceID="DataSource1" Width="100%" CssClass="dataTable" 
                 PageSize="15" ShowFooter="True" CellPadding="5" 
                 CellSpacing="5" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True"
                 EmptyDataText="No records available in database" 
                 OnRowUpdating = "UpdateTableRecordInDatabase" 
                 OnRowDeleting="ListOfTables_RowDeleting">

                 <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle CssClass="sortasc" />
                 <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle CssClass="sortdesc" />

                 <columns>.....</columns>
                </asp:GridView>
                <asp:SQLDataSource .....>....</asp:SqlDataSource>
             </ContentTemplate>

            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ListOfTables" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

**Code 2**

```
Protected Sub UpdateTableRecordInDatabase(sender As Object, e As GridViewUpdateEventArgs)
   If CheckForDuplicateRecords(intAccountID, strTableName) = FALSE then
      code here to update the table
   else
      e.Cancel = TRUE
      Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri)
      PrintExceptionStatus("Table Names should be unique")
   end if

End Sub

Sub PrintExceptionStatus(strMessage As String)

    lblStatus.Visible = True
    lblStatus.BackColor = Drawing.Color.LightYellow
    lblStatus.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
    lblStatus.Text = "<img src='Images/error.png' align='absmiddle' hspace='5'>" + strMessage.ToString()

End Sub
```

Is there anything which I am overlooking or missing. Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the `GridView` that fires the event is inside the `UpdatePanel`. Here is how it works - when the postback is triggered by something inside the `UpdatePanel`, the whole page life cycle is run, but then only the part of the page inside the `UpdatePanel` is updated on the client page.

So, after the `GridView` triggers the event, the text of the label is changed in the code behind (as you can see in debug), but since it is not inside the `UpdatePanel` the label is not changed, as you can see.

To solve the issue simply move the label inside the `UpdatePanel` - this make it a part of the HTML that is updated when postback inside `UpdatePanel` occurs:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="TablesUpdatePanel" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" visible="false"></asp:Label>
```

Note that since it is inside the template, you might need `FindControl` now to access the label.

Comment: Thanks @Andrei, let me work on this and will share the outcome. Thanks very much

Comment: Hi @Andrei, I did what you mentioned. To check, I harcoded the text in the Label to check whether the code is overwriting but still no luck. `Sub PrintExceptionStatus(ByVal strMessage As String)
        Dim objLabel As Label = CType(TablesUpdatePanel.FindControl("lblStatus"), Label)
            objLabel.Visible = True
            objLabel.Text = "Hello World!"
            objLabel.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Blue
            objLabel.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.White
    End Sub`

Comment: @YashmanGupta, actyually Swapy has a point here as well. What is `Redirect` for here? If you want ot stay on the same page and just update the control state, it is not needed and should be removed

Comment: I found out and yes Swapy is right..it is because of Redirect. With this I was trying to exit the Grid Edit mode. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you execute the UpdateTableRecordInDatabase the debugger goes in the if block or else block? If it goes in the else block you have written:

```
  Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri)
```

and after that you have called

```
  PrintExceptionStatus("Table Names should be unique")
```

so in this case Page will be redirected to the given URL and if you have given URL as that of the current page it will definitely make the label to visible false as again the page load event will occur so try commenting Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri)

Comment: Thanks @Swapy, I have tried that as well but still it does not work

Comment: what happens when you comment Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri) does it executes the PrintExceptionStatus

Comment: it goes inside the code with a proper message in string but the .NET page does not show anything. not even the label control is getting visible.

Comment: ok your label is outside the update panel you need to get your label inside update panel that's why it's not updating the label to visible true as it's outside of update panel so get this label inside update panel and try this should work <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" visible="false"></asp:Label>

Comment: thanks for your help. I tried to mark yours and Andrei as answer but unfortunately I cannot.

Comment: It's fine @Yashman it's cool you got to know your problem and the solution :)